# Is Lagrange multiplier useful in this Constrained optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization, constraints

I'm trying to numerically solve the following optimization problem.
Let $u \in R^{n \times n_c}$ be the variable we wish to find.
Let $\phi$ be the objective:

$\phi = Tr(u^\top L u) + 1/2 ||u - u^{obs} ||_2^2 $   st. $u e_{n_c} = 0_n$

where $u^{obs}$ is given, $L \in R^{n \times n}$ is a known graph Laplacian, and $e_{n_c}$ is the vector of ones, with length $n_c$.

We can rewrite this using Lagrange multipliers as:

$\phi = Tr(u^\top L u) + 1/2 ||u - u^{obs} ||_2^2 + \lambda_n^\top u e_{n_c}$

where $\lambda_n$ is the lagrange multiplier, which is a vector of length $n$.
The theory now says to take the derivative of the objective with regards to $u$ and $\lambda$, which gives me:

$\frac{ \partial \phi }{\partial u} = 2 L u + (u - u^{obs}) + \lambda_n e_{n_c}^\top = 0_{n \times n_c}$

$\frac{\partial \phi} {\partial \lambda} = u e_{n_c} = 0_n$

Now the idea is to combine these two equations and eliminate $\lambda$ if possible, but I don't see any way I can combine this and get something I could solve algebraically or numerically.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could proceed?

Comment: basically the long and short of it is:

Lagrange multipliers doesn't work in 1 dimension. (That's to say it is no different to just standard setting the gradient equal to zero)
Here you take the derivative with respect to $u$ only. If you had two input vectors then lagrange multipliers would be suitable.

Comment: Maybe try add term $\epsilon\|ue_{n_c}\|_2^2$?

Comment: Why lowercase for matrices?

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst  I guess that makes sense, but do you have any idea how I can combine my constraints into the system of equations then?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo just for clarity of their dimensions

Comment: Very messy. You don't even mention if your maximizing or minimizing.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thats your personal preference, I find it quite informative when I'm working on something new. Regarding the optimization, it is obvious from the structure that I'm minimizing the problem.

Comment: @mathreadler this would turn the problem into an augmented Lagrangian if I'm not much mistaken?
I guess I could introduce a dual variable and solve it as an ADMM problem this way, though I was hoping not to go down that path, since won't be an easy or fast solution.

Comment: Is including `s.t.` in the objective your personal preference or merely an error?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo That is also fairly standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centering matrix is constructed from the identity matrix and the all-ones vector
$$\eqalign{
C = I - \frac{ee^T}{e^Te} \quad\implies\quad
 C^2=C=C^T,\quad Ce = 0
}$$
Construct the matrix $U$ from $C$ and an ***unconstrained*** matrix variable $X$.
$$\eqalign{
U &= XC \quad\implies\quad 
Ue &= 0,\quad
UC &= U \\
}$$
Write the objective function and calculate its gradient wrt $X$.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= L:UU^T + \tfrac{1}{2}(U-U_{obs}):(U-U_{obs}) \\
d\phi
 &= L:(U\,dU^T+dU\,U^T) + (U-U_{obs}):dU \\
 &= \Big((L+L^T)U + U-U_{obs}\Big):dU \\
 &= \big(LU+L^TU + U-U_{obs}\big):dX\,C \\
 &= (LU + L^TU + U - U_{obs}C):dX \\
 &= ((L + L^T + I)U - U_{obs}C):dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X}
 &= (L + L^T + I)U - U_{obs}C \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal matrix.
$$\eqalign{
 0 &= (L + L^T + I)U - U_{obs}C \\
 U &= (L + L^T + I)^{-1}U_{obs}C \\
}$$
**NB:** A colon is being used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$

Terms in such products can be rearranged via the cyclic property of 
the trace, e.g. 
$$\eqalign{A:BC = B^TA:C = AC^T:B}$$

#### Update

There was a question about where $C$ came from.

Consider the general solution of a linear equation
$$AX=B \quad\implies\quad A = BX^+ + Y(I-XX^+)$$
where $X^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $X$, the matrix $Y$ is arbitrary, and 
$(I-XX^+)$ is a projector into the nullspace, i.e. $\;(I-XX^+)X=0$.

For real vectors, the pseudoinverse can be written in terms of the transpose, i.e. $\;e^+=\frac{e^T}{e^Te}$.

Now consider the constraint as a linear equation to be solved for $U$, and
note that $C$ is the nullspace projector for $e$.

Comment: That was absolutely amazing and humbling to read, thank you so much for taking the time to write this!
If you don't mind me asking, how did you get the idea to create C in that way? That seems like complete magic to me.

Comment: I updated to my answer to address the origin of the $C$ matrix.

Comment: If you wish to salvage your original Lagrange multipliers approach, then add the missing $L^Tu$ term to the first gradient and multiply through by $e$. The second gradient tells you that all the $ue$ terms become zero, allowing you to solve for $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer to my question, by using the Laplace multipler I can solve  the combined system in vectorized form, which for $n_c=2$ looks like:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha L + I  & 0  & I \\
    0 & \alpha L + I & I \\
    I & I & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \bar{u}_1 \\
    \bar{u}_2  \\
    \lambda \\
    \end{pmatrix} =     
\begin{pmatrix}
    \bar{u}^{obs}_1 \\
    \bar{u}^{obs}_2  \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

where
$ u = \begin{pmatrix}
    \vdots & \vdots  \\
    \bar{u}_1 & \bar{u}_2 \\
    \vdots & \vdots \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$